# Как на swing организовать commander

Tags: java, swing

Задача написать что-то в стиле Total Comander-a на swing. 
Вопрос в том, на основе чего делать список файлов. Хочется, чтобы была возможность двигать размеры колоног тип, размер, дата и двигаться по списку клавишами. 
JTable не очень подходит, потому что при нажатии вправо выделенная ячейка будет сдвигаться куда не положено (на колонку даты, например). 
Совсем шикарно, если бы можно было сделать этот список полосатым. 
Не подскажете, как лучше это организовать?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что вы имеете в виду под фразой "на основе чего" - на основе какой структуры/на основе каких средств/lib в java, или как получить список файлов из ОС. 
Также могли вы бы точнее сформулировать требования к программе?

Comment: На основе какой структуры swing-а. с файлами проблем нет, проблема именно в организации части gui, отвечающий за отображение списка фейлов.